# WorksheetReader openpyxl too many arguments TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, conda, openpyxl, spyder

I still learning python and running into an error that I cannot figure out.

I am just trying to take the results from a sql statement and paste it into an existing template and then save the results with a new name with today's date in it.

My Error:

```
File openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:342 in openpyxl.worksheet._reader.WorksheetReader.__init__

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 positional arguments (6 given)
```

My Script:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

# Set up your database connection details
conn_str = (
    r'DSN=SQL_PROD;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)

sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM SQL_DB_Sandbox.aatest_python'

df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)

book = load_workbook('existing_file.xlsx')

current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'new_file_{current_date}.xlsx') 
writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, startcol=0, index=False)

writer.save()
```

I have ensured that the existing_file.xlsx is in the same directory as the .py file.
I am using pandas (1.3.4) and openpyxl (3.1.2).

Comment: Please include complete traceback.